# Vue JS hover problems

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two images when hovering the mouse over one of these images, a certain component is displayed if it says more in detail when hovering over the first image, a component with a red background is displayed, and when hovering over the second image, a component with a yellow background is displayed

And so what is my problem in fact my real code looks very different I just wrote a small piece of code in codesandbox so that you can understand my problem instead of a yellow component on my real project a large stylized component with data is displayed

My problem is that when I want to interact with the yellow or red content they disappear I want to click on the button that is located on one of these components, but it does not work because they disappear I tried to apply @mouseout for the drop-down components but in this case the architecture of the code is destroyed because the mouse hover already works incorrectly

I understand that my thoughts that I want to explain sounds confusing, but I hope you understand my problem here is the link of [my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-hover-animation-ycnrt) in the codesandbox

**myothercomponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo
      accusamus quod quis voluptatibus dolor magni, pariatur accusantium fugit
      itaque sint
    </p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "myOtherComponent",
};
</script>
```

**myycomponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo
      accusamus quod quis voluptatibus dolor magni, pariatur accusantium fugit
      itaque sint
    </p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyFirstComponent",
};
</script>
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
      <div v-bind:key="index" v-for="(girl, index) in girls">
        <img
          style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 5px"
          @mouseover="mouseOver(girl)"
          @mouseout="mouseout(girl)"
          v-bind:src="girl.imgSrc"
          alt="Snow"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-for="(girl, index) in girls" v-bind:key="index">
      <slide-y-up-transition>
        <component
          v-show="girl.hovered"
          v-bind:is="girl.componentName"
        ></component>
      </slide-y-up-transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { SlideYUpTransition } from "vue2-transitions";
import MyFirstComponent from "./colors/myycomponent";
import myOtherComponent from "./colors/myothercomponent";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    MyFirstComponent,
    myOtherComponent,
    SlideYUpTransition,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      componentNames: ["MyFirstComponent", "myOtherComponent"],
      girls: [
        {
          imgSrc: "https://html5css.ru/css/img_lights.jpg",
          hovered: false,
          hoverColor: "#337700",
          componentName: "MyFirstComponent",
        },
        {
          imgSrc: "https://html5css.ru/css/img_lights.jpg",
          hovered: false,
          hoverColor: "#123456",
          componentName: "myOtherComponent",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    mouseOver: function (girl) {
      girl.hovered = true;
    },

    mouseout: function (girl) {
      girl.hovered = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood problem right, try to change @mouseout event to @mouseleave event, and check if it works in behaviour that u wanna :D

```
<template>
<div>
 <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
  <div v-bind:key="index" v-for="(girl, index) in girls">
    <img
      style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 5px"
      @mouseover="mouseOver(girl)"
      v-bind:src="girl.imgSrc"
      alt="Snow"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div v-for="(girl, index) in girls" v-bind:key="index" @mouseleave="mouseout(girl)">
  <slide-y-up-transition>
    <component
      v-show="girl.hovered"
      v-bind:is="girl.componentName"
    ></component>
  </slide-y-up-transition>
</div>
```

Also i think if u wanna hover on next image, u should hide other colored blocks like

```
mouseOver: function (girl) {
  this.girls.forEach((girl) => (girl.hovered = false));
  girl.hovered = true;
},
```